# ASP.NET Scss bundle transformations really slow

Tags: asp.net, bundletransformer

I used to use less, whiched using V8 to render the style sheets, but now I am using scss, and it is using IronRuby to compile the style sheets.

With that said, my startup time in my application is SLOWW!

With the debugger, I see where the pause is happening.

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles")
```

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Should I just use web essentials and reference the compiled css?

Comment: What about using http://sass-lang.com/libsass on windows? Then, we can us P-Invoke or C++/CLI to invoke it. I imagine that would be quicker than running the entire Ruby engine in .NET, since libsass is just c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, all bundle transformations are ignored. While bundling should have no performance impact, minimization can be problematic depending on the code. I usually avoid the minimization function of ASP.net.

You should either pre-compile your scss files using Web Essentials or another plugin, and then use the built-in bundling to wrap them together. Also, make sure to define your bundle manually (define each file to include).

Bundles are cached for 1 year once created so while the first page load can be slow, all subsequent calls should be quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

In [Bundle Transformer 1.9.81](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/releases/view/618390) due to the transition to [libSass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) has been significantly increased performance of BundleTransformer.SassAndScss module.